# ref.on(...) isn't called when selecting a subset of a Firebase array

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have two arrays, $scope.messages and $scope.aggregatedMessages. $scope.messages is in bound to a Firebase array. The $scope.messages have a date property which is used to show only the messages from a certain date. Very simple. When a new message is added or the user changes the date I want the aggregatedMessages array to be reloaded.

```
$scope.messages = $firebaseArray(ref.orderByChild("date").equalTo(date));
```

... is used to bind the $scope.messages array with Firebase. When selecting a new date the above function is called again.

and

```
ref.on("value", function(value) {
...
});
```

... is used to rebuild the aggregatedMessages array when something changes (I know, should use child_added and such instead... and I will later on :).

Now, this doesn't work since Firebase doesn't call my callback function (in ref.on) when a new item is added to $scope.messages, how ever $scope.messages.$add(...) do work and does what it is supposed to.

What is the best practice for this kind of situation?

Comment: Can you provide the code that would trigger the on value callback? Also, when using AngularFire you usually don't need to write the on callbacks as AF handles the synchronization automatically.

Answer (score 0):

best practice is not to rebuild your firebaseArray, if data are added to the firebase ref they will be synced automatically.

```
$scope.messages = $firebaseArray(ref.orderByChild("date").equalTo(date));

$scope.messages.$ref().on('child_added', function(snap){
  console.log(snap.key(), snap.val());
})

ref.push(data)
// > console will log the new data key and value if data.date == date
```

if you have to rebuild a firebaseArray, do not forget to call $destroy on it before to delete it, to tell firebase not to listen anymore to the ref and clear memory

```
$scope.messages.$destroy()
$scope.messages = $firebaseArray(ref.orderByChild("date").equalTo(aNewDate));
```

Comment: I know. But the aggregatedMessages array is not a Firebase array. Since it is not possible to aggregate data in Firebase directly I need a way to build a new array (aggregatedMessages), for example showing a topic and number of messages in a sidebar. And this is better done by iterating through the messages stored in Firebase and rebuild the non-Firebase aggregatedMessages array (ok, it is a bad name though:)

So I want to be able to listen to changes on messages array, even when I am only working on a subset of the array (when I select an array using ref.orderByChild("date").equalTo(newDate))

Comment: ... and you want to be able to iterate over both your array and your aggregated one ?

Comment: Yes. But what I am trying to understand with Firebase is if I have a ref which points to my list of messages. Then I want to get a another ref to a subset of the messages list. For example, ref -> { 12, 20, 43, 67, 98 }. Now I want a new ref, subsetRef = ref.startAt(20).endAt(67) which gives me: sunsetRef = { 20, 43, 67 }. If I start listen on changes on ref and on subsetRef, will a change e.g. $firebaseArray(ref).$add(25) also trigger the subsetRef.on(...) function with a new value of 25?